# Is there a way to add hover class on series click and remove it on unselect Event in HighCharts?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am trying to use the hover effect on select and want to remove it when unselected.

I have tried to search for methods to do that, but could not able to find anything.

Comment: Please follow this [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Check this example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/rt1f0nk9/